# How to make elegant separation between technical proof and its meaning?

Tags: page-layout, critique, microsoft-word

I would like to have a visual separation between a normal text (above the line) and its explanation (under the line) so that the readers can easily notice the difference when skimming the article. So far I have used a simple line to separate like this:

[image]

I feel something uncomfortable to my eyes, but I can't name it. I would like to know what's wrong and how to improve it.

Because this is a scientific article, I don't want to overdecorate it, just be clean and neat. I don't think it is a good idea to use ornaments. The program in use is MS Word.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think the line doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think it doesn't work. In fact, I still somewhat satisfied with it. I just wonder if the decoration is suitable in the scientific context. I want to attract the readers, in a scientific way.

Comment: @Ooker "I use word". Use TeX or LaTeX, and it will be done for you

Comment: I, personally, would use a different typeface, or weight for the equations to separate them from the text a bit more visually. But that's merely  a preference.

Comment: @Scott would adding more space above and below the equations work?

Comment: Yes some. but I don't know that that is absolutely necessary if the font/weight were changed. Customarily, I like to offset equations specifically in a medium weight sans-serif font and indent (as you have).  i'd indent the right edge of the bullets as well though. -- still just my preferences. I don't think what you have is bad by any means.

Comment: @Scott why indent the right edge of the bullets?

Comment: Because they are flush with the other text. There's visual separation on the left, but not the right.

Comment: @Scott sorry, I don't understand you. What text is the other text? Are you talking about the spaces on the left and on the right of the bullets?

Comment: After reading actual answers (which I didn't do before)... @DA01 pretty much sums up how I'd indent. I wouldn't necessarily use the line myself, but the white space is close to what I'd use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the full context but here's my interpretation. I think there are two things that need to be accomplished.

1. Visually stylize the proof/explanation area differently than the rest of the content.
2. Separate the content from the proof/explanation.

I'd suggest judicious use of white space...both vertically (space between paragraphs/sections) as well as horizontally (indent the proof/explanation area).

A line works well, but it can be subtle. You don't need to make it large and dark. Example:

[image]

Comment: Do dissertations have any sort of paper limit either by requirement or by cost? If not this is a very good option.

Comment: Wow, you have spent your time to cut and rearrange my picture. I appreciate that. I'll accept this.
@Ryan: thank you too. Luckily I'm not so much pressure to follow the requirement. This is a very good one indeed.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I would keep it in essence, but differentiate by either/or:

- Make the text line italic, bigger font or bold
- Make the distance from text line to equation bigger

I would *remove the left justified* on the text lines. It looks bad when the variation in spaces between the words gets so pronounced.

---

**Edit I:**

By removing the left justified, I mean that this sentence gets very weird spaces between the words. 
[image]

You see they are placed so that the sentence takes up the whole space. The sentence below the equations are *not* left justified, so that looks better.

---

**Edit II:**
As to how big a gap between text and equation;... well. The same as the distance between your paragraphs.

These may be of interest:

**[Font for section and subsections, titles in scientific thesis](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28955/font-for-sections-subsections-and-subsubsection-titles-in-scientific-thesis)**

**[Layout for technical documents](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/layout-for-technical-documents)**

**[How much space between two paragraphs](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21749/how-much-space-should-i-leave-between-two-paragraphs)**

**[Readability as a function of measure and leading](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/readability-as-a-function-of-measure-and-leading)**

Comment: It is nice. However, instead of bolding the text, I see that fading the line is better. However, which did you mean "left justified"? I don't see any.

Comment: @Ooker see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh yes. I have actually noticed that. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fading the line", but whatever you do, make the spaces between sentences and equations bigger.

Comment: It is like this: http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/how-to-quickly-insert-horizontal-line-in-word-2010-document/. I think you are right, it seem to be tightly here. However, if I do that, the last paragraph will be displayed in a new page. I don't think I could strip any words, so do you think should I keep that spacing to keep the chapter fit the pages perfectly?

Comment: This is kinda a different question, about page layout, but generally: I would reconsider the general structure of the document. There is a good chance you are not using whitespace to good use other places too. I would give good space to headings, tables, quotes; I would increase line-height overall. I would look at page-brakes. And I would look at margins. Be generous with white-space. It makes it easier to read for your advisors. An then at last there is the functionality of assigning to a block of text "do not separate over pages".

Comment: Thanks. Then how much space you would advise? Like an enter?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Random O'Reilly. Especially in regards to the justified text. Only alternative I would also consider for the separator is a double line instead of a single.

Here I used the same size double lines as in your equal sign:

[image]